# In C: function that sums items in array returning weird large number

Tags: c, arrays, parameters

This program is supposed to take input, put it in an array and output the item #, items in stock, and the sum of the items in the array. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20

void print_inventory(int inventory[], int numitems);

int input_inventory(int inventory[], int maxnum);

int sum_array(int inventory[], int numitems);

int main()
{
    int inventory[MAX];
    int num_items;

    printf("Please enter the number of items in stock. ");
    printf("Enter -1 when you are done.\n");

    num_items = input_inventory(inventory, MAX);

    print_inventory(inventory, num_items);

    return 0;
}

int input_inventory(int inventory[], int maxnum)
{
    int index=0;

    scanf("%d", &inventory[index]);
    while (index < maxnum-1 && inventory[index] != -1){
        index++;
        scanf("%d", &inventory[index]);
    }
    if (index == maxnum-1){
        printf("No room for more items.\n");
        return(index+1);
    }
    else 
        return (index);
}

void print_inventory(int inventory[], int numitems)
{
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < numitems; index++){
        printf("Item number %d:\t\t", index+1);
        printf("Number on hand %5d\n", inventory[index]);
    }
    printf("The total number of items is %d.\n", sum_array(inventory,      numitems));

}

int sum_array(int inventory[], int num)
{
    int sum, index;

    for(index=0; index < num; index++)
        sum += inventory[index];

    return (sum);
}
```

When I input the numbers: `7, 4, 6, 7, 9, -1`, the output is `32767`. Which is totally not true. Any idea what's wrong with my `sum_array` function?

Comment: You never initialize sum, so this code produces undefined behavior. Try `int sum = 0, index`. You can also remove the parentheses in `return (sum)` as they have no effect.

Comment: A common problem arising out of not initializing the variables. The "wierd" number is technically called the garbage value. Issue should be resolved if you correctly initialize the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `sum` to zero:

```
int sum_array(int inventory[], int num)
{
    int sum = 0, index;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    for(index=0; index < num; index++)
        sum += inventory[index];

    return (sum);
}
```